# Get correct path of selected node in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating my own File Explorer, I have most of my desired functionality working however I am stuck at displaying the correct path to the user.

I have a **TreeView** which displays folders for the current directory and I have a **WebBrowser** which displays the content of the selected node.  I have **TreeView_DoubleClick** event which upon selecting a folder in TreeView, it displays the content of that folder inside WebBrowser.

The problem -

Example scenario with path being C:/Example-

Inside C:/Example there is folder A, B and C, and inside each of them, there is A1, B1 and C1... making the path C:/Example/A/A1 and so on.

What I currently have is a textbox which has a hard-coded path when the application is initially opened and inside my double click event I have created a string called **_NewPath** which is equalled to -

```
    pathTxt.Text + "\\" + treeView1.SelectedNode.Text.
```

And I set the update Url like this -

```
    webBrowser.Url = new Uri(_NewPath);
```

If I double click the node for the first time it works no problem - C:/Example/A and going even lower is fine too - C:/Example/A/A1 however if I try to climb back up the tree my path then messes up to C:/Example/A/B and so on (having the previous path and appending to the end new path which doesn't exist).

Any nudge in the right direction is highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: The code you're describing won't do what you claim. You'll never get a path that way, just the prefix prepended to the text of the selected node only. So please share the actual code. I assume you're appending the text of every node you select to `_NewPath` and never removing any of it, so if you select node "X" three times in a row, you'll get "C:\X\X\X\". But that's a guess. Please don't ask us to guess. It's not a productive use of anybody's time.

Comment: What you're looking for is a recursive function.

Comment: @EdPlunkett responding to your first comment, you're correct that is what I'm doing and I'm aware of the fact that my desired functionality will never work with the current implementation, sorry for not enough detail, I will update my question soon. I will read up on recursive functions and see if I'm able to work out a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had managed to find a better solution myself. While the above answer works well, it depends on the textbox value and it will only work inside the path that begins with textbox value.

My solution is -

```
 private void TreeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode newSelected = e.Node;
        DirectoryInfo _NewPath = (DirectoryInfo)newSelected.Tag;
        if(_NewPath != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_NewPath.FullName))
        {
            webBrowser.Url = new Uri(_NewPath.FullName);
        }
    }
```

Inside my **NodeMouseClick** event I have created **newSelected** which is a TreeNode.
Using this I have created new object of type **DirectoryInfo** called **_NewPath**, which is equalled to selected treeNode.Tag and casted to DirectoryInfo.

With that, the **DirectoryInfo FullName** provides the current full path of the selected node, whereas **TreeNode** would only provide the path from where the application started.

Lastly, I made some null check and set my **webBrowser.Url** value to the **_NewPath.FullName**.